# How to write correct C# GraphClient filter to retrieve users with ExternalUserState = null?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I don't manage to create a filter to get the users that have null in the ExternalUserState property

My attempts:

```
var users = await graphClient.Users.Request()
                            .Filter("ExternalUserState eq null")
                            .Select(u => new {
                                u.Id,
                                u.DisplayName,
                                u.ExternalUserState,
                                u.ExternalUserStateChangeDateTime
                            })
                            .GetAsync();

                            // .Filter("ExternalUserState not in ('PendingAcceptance', 'Accepted')"
```

Both filters *"ExternalUserState eq null"* and (in another attempt) filter *"ExternalUserState not in ('PendingAcceptance', 'Accepted')"* result in **Invalid filter clause**

The User.ExternalUserState attribute Help mentions:

> Returned only on $select. Supports $filter (eq, ne, not, in)

Any idea how to compose a working filter?

Comment: I'm not sure what RDBMS are you using, but usually `null` is not equal to itself. So, instead of `eq`, you probably need `is` or something of the like, depending on what RDBMS and ORM you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries#user-properties), `externalUserState` does not support filtering on `null` values